# Kivy, Odd and Inconsistent Ball Movement (Animation)

Tags: python, animation, kivy, kivy-language

Can someone please explain why the movement of the ball(image) is inconsistent and very random?

Can someone please suggest a fix, as I'm very confused?

I'm using the Screen Class and animation which deploys the function whenever a button is clicked, to make the ball(image) move.

Please watch the video and take a look at the code as it would make more sense then.

---

Heres a video of it exactly:
https://streamable.com/rahsm0

---

Py Code:

```
num = 0.48
movement = 0.025
movementt = 0.1


class L1(Screen):
    screensize()

    def animate_down_button(self, widget, *args):
        global num
        global movement
        global movementt
        newnum = num - movement
        num -= movement
        anim = Animation(y_hint=num - movement, duration=movementt)
        anim.start(widget)
        pass

    def animate_up_button(self, widget, *args):
        global num
        global movement
        newnum = num + movement
        num += movement
        anim = Animation(y_hint=num + movement, duration=movementt)
        anim.start(widget)
        pass

    def animate_right_button(self, widget, *args):
        global num
        global movement
        newnum = num + movement
        num += movement
        anim = Animation(x_hint=num + movement, duration=movementt)
        anim.start(widget)
        pass

    def animate_left_button(self, widget, *args):
        global num
        global movement
        newnum = num - movement
        num -= movement
        anim = Animation(x_hint=num - movement, duration=movementt)
        anim.start(widget)
        pass

    def play_nav(self):
        if nav:
            nav.play()
```

Kv Code:

```
Button:
    pos_hint: {"x":0.01, "top":0.995}
    size_hint: 0.15, 0.075
    background_normal: 'BackArrow.png'
    background_down: 'BackArrowPressed.png'
    on_release: root.play_nav()
    on_release: app.root.current = "GameMenu"
Image:
    id: mazeball
    source: 'ball.png'
    size_hint: 0.07, 0.07
    x_hint: 0.53
    y_hint: 0.48
    pos_hint: {"x": self.x_hint, "top": self.y_hint}
Button:
    pos_hint: {"x":0.4375, "top":0.21}
    size_hint: 0.125, 0.125
    background_normal: 'PadDown.png'
    background_down: 'PadDownPressed.png'
    on_release: root.play_nav()
    on_release: root.animate_down_button(mazeball)

Button:
    pos_hint: {"x":0.4375, "top":0.35}
    size_hint: 0.125, 0.125
    background_normal: 'PadUp.png'
    background_down: 'PadUpPressed.png'
    on_release: root.play_nav()
    on_press: root.animate_up_button(mazeball)
Button:
    pos_hint: {"x":0.5375, "top": 0.28}
    size_hint: 0.125, 0.125
    background_normal: 'PadRight.png'
    background_down: 'PadRightPressed.png'
    on_release: root.play_nav()
    on_release: root.animate_right_button(mazeball)
Button:
    pos_hint: {"x":0.3375, "top": 0.28}
    size_hint: 0.125, 0.125
    background_normal: 'PadLeft.png'
    background_down: 'PadLeftPressed.png'
    on_release: root.play_nav()
    on_release: root.animate_left_button(mazeball)
```

Comment: I haven't looked through in detail, but it's likely that rather than the movement being random it's simply that your understanding of how you're setting the target positions is wrong. Have you tried logging and carefully inspecting the values of the variables during each press, to see where they first take values you didn't expect? If you can find that, you know what part of the code is wrong.

Comment: without minimal working code which we could simply copy and run we can only suggest to use `print()` to display values in variables. Maybe they have value different then you expect.

Comment: you don't change value in `movement` `movementt` so you don't need to use `global`. You calculate `newnum` but never use this variable so maybe remove it. First you chagen `num` lik `num += movement` and alter you use `y_hint=num + movement` - so you add `movement` two times.

Comment: for most buttons you run animation in `on_release` but for one button in `on_press` and I think you should user `on_press` for all buttons.

Comment: @furas 
I will use debugger and print to try and solve the issue now, but I made `y_hint = num` and that solved the double jump issue, the only thing left to fix is, when changing direction its movement is weird. 

I just have one question, instead of on_press/on_release, do you know of a way to make that 'WHILE' i am pressing the button a loop is repeating? for example in my case holding the up button would constantly move the character up, etc. 

If we could talk more 1 on 1, (snap, insta, WhatsApp etc, please let me know, id love more help(Im new to this))

Comment: I think you should do it similar to  PyGame - which runs `while True` all time and it check buttons - and `on_press` sets variables `x_move = movment`  or `y_move = movment`  and `on_release`  sets variables `x_move = 0`  or `y_move = 0` . And `while True` check these values in every loop and move object. In `Kivy` you can't use `while True` because it will block loop which Kivy already use - but you can use `Clock.schedule_interval(my_callback, 1/30.)` - see [Events](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/events.html)